# Shell scripting: Check if file exists in directory from a list file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to check if file names listed in a text file exist in a directory. If the file name in medialist.txt exists in the medialab directory put the file name in foundfiles.txt otherwise put the file name in lostfiles.txt. Where I am having difficulty is passing a single file name from medialist.txt into the if statement. How would I pass a single file name from medialist.txt to the if statement?

The following block of code is what I have come up with so far.

```
for i in $(cat /home/user/Downloads/medialab/medialist.txt)
do
   if [[ $([[ -e $i ]]) == $(ls /home/user/Downloads/medialab/)  ]]
   then
           echo "$i" > /home/user/foundfiles.txt
   else
           echo "$i" > /home/user/lostfiles.txt
   fi
done
```

I have experimented with the xargs command in the if statement. This would replace the current if statement in the for loop above. I would  remove the LS variable, it is just for testing the if statement on its own.
Here is the example:

```
LS=$(ls /home/user/Downloads/medialab/)

if [[ -e $(xargs echo "$LS") ]]
then    
    echo "$i" > /home/user/foundfiles.txt
else    
    echo "$i" > /home/user/lostfiles.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the file in a while-loop and check if the path is a file with the `-f` (checks if the given path is a file) switch, like so:

```
while read -r || [[ -n $REPLY ]]; do
    [[ -z $REPLY ]] && continue
    if [[ -f "/home/user/Downloads/medialab/${REPLY}" ]]; then
        echo "$REPLY" >> "/home/user/foundfiles.txt"
    else
        echo "$REPLY" >> "/home/user/lostfiles.txt"
    fi
done < "/home/user/Downloads/medialab/medialist.txt"
```

What's happening here is we're reading the inputfile with a redirection to the while loop, using `read` to read the input into a variable using the inbuilt `$REPLY` variable, then the `|| [[ -n $REPLY ]]` handles an inputfile that doesn't end with a newline.

Next we check if the variable is empty with `-z`, this handles empty lines in the middle of the file skipping them with `continue`.

Then we check if the string in the now populated `$REPLY` variable is a file with `-f` (expanding the filename as a part of the path in quotes) and append the appropriate file with `>>`.

Note how using `[[` as the test, you don't need to quote the LHS variable, but you do need to quote a RHS variable (as well as variables in pretty much any other use).

Comment: Note also that @Olli K used "double-greater-thans" to put the file names in the _foundfiles.txt_ and _lostfiles.txt_ files.  This **appends** to the file while the single greater-than you used wipes the file each time, resulting in a single record in the file.

Comment: I assume `while read -r ||` was intended to be `while read -r REPLY ||`.  Double quotes are not strictly required in `[[ ]]` on the RHS ; however, unquoted RHS in `=`, `==` and `!=` tests may trigger pattern matching, and this is often best avoided (as is the case here).

Comment: @Fred No, just `read -r`. If no names are supplied to `read`, the line read is assigned to the variable `REPLY`

Comment: @OlliK  Ok.  I always use explicit variable names, so I did not think of that.  `REPLY` is a bit confusing as a variable name in a non-interactive scenario.

Comment: Well, using a name here is also fine, I've just usually used `REPLY` especially in examples to save keystrokes ;)

Comment: If you are going to be lazy, why not name the variable `r`...  Because of the number of times it is repeated, that would be even fewer keystrokes... :)

Comment: @OlliK The first version of your solution worked better than the second version. I tried both. The second version resulted in only one file name in foundfiles.txt and lostfiles.txt. The first version resulted in 189 file names in foundfiles.txt and 5 file names in lostfiles.txt. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn The single greater-thans is intentional as I was running this script multiple times during testing. I did not want to have to clear the files each time I ran the script. I now understand that what you are trying say. I had not realized this. Thanks!